# WordPress polylang перевод корзины WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Не совсем понимаю, как перевести корзину. У меня на сайте три языка.
http://urprotection.ch/en/cart

В polylang если открыть перевод строк, там не будет нужных. По сути, нужно как-то добавить туда эти строки, но я не понимаю что куда. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Бесплатная версия Polylang не поддерживает перевод для WooCommerce.

Попробуйте плагин [Hyyan WooCommerce Polylang Integration](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-poly-integration/), у него есть поддержка WooCommerce, в том числе корзины.

Answer (score 0):

Менял сам в коде с помощью специальной вставки.